# How to programmatically generate create table statement based on data frame

Tags: python, json, pyspark, avro

I'm trying to have a function to create Hive table based on the `data` part of avro data. The schema for the source data is like below. The target table needs to be partitioned by `partition` field in the source data, with two columns `name` and `description`. I can get the source `data` part by `df.select('data.*')` and the table schema by `df.select('data.*').schema`, but `partition` column is not in there. My goal is to have a create table clause `create table mytable (name string, description string) partitioned by (partition integer) store as parquet` How do I do this? Do I need to append `df.select('partition.*')` to df.select('data.*') first? Many thanks for your help.

Edited: The goal is that you wouldn't need to specify the level of columns, like data.name and partition, but only pass in "columns" and "partition column" (which can be at any nested level, and then generate a create table statement.

```
root
|--metadata: struct
|   |---id: string
|   |---time : string
|--data:struct
|   |---name : string
|   |---description : string
|--partition:integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following self-contained example shows you how you can create and write the table that you specify. You need to provide your own `path_for_saving`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

schema = T.StructType([
          T.StructField('metadata', T.StructType([
            T.StructField("id",T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("time",T.StringType())])),
          T.StructField('data', T.StructType([
            T.StructField("name",T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("description",T.StringType()),
          ])),
          T.StructField("partition", T.IntegerType()),
          T.StructField("Level1", T.StructType([
            T.StructField("Level2",T.StructType([
              T.StructField("Level3", T.StructType([
                T.StructField("partition_alt", T.IntegerType())]))]))]))
         ])
df_sample_data = spark.createDataFrame([(("id1", "time1"), ("name1", "desc1"), 1, (((3,),),)), (("id2", "time2"), ("name2", "desc2"), 2, (((4,),),)) ], schema)
df_sample_data.printSchema()
df_sample_data.show()

def parse_fields(schema, path=""):
  collect = []
  for struct_field in schema:
    this_field_name = struct_field.name
    if type(struct_field.dataType) == T.StructType:
      collect = collect + parse_fields(struct_field.dataType, path + this_field_name + ".")
    else: 
      collect = collect + [path + this_field_name]
  return collect

parsed_fields = parse_fields(schema) # Find all leaf fields in the schema and return as '.' seperated path
print("Parsed fields:" + str(parsed_fields))
def get_column(col_name):
  for field in parsed_fields:
    if col_name in field:
      return F.col(field).alias(col_name)
    
name_col = "name"
description_col = "description"
partition_col = "partition_alt"

df_mytable = df_sample_data.select(get_column(name_col), get_column(description_col), get_column(partition_col))
df_mytable.show()

df_mytable.write.partitionBy(partition_col).format("parquet").save(path_for_saving)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Level1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Level2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Level3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- partition_alt: integer (nullable = true)

+------------+--------------+---------+-------+
|    metadata|          data|partition| Level1|
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+
|{id1, time1}|{name1, desc1}|        1|{{{3}}}|
|{id2, time2}|{name2, desc2}|        2|{{{4}}}|
+------------+--------------+---------+-------+

Parsed fields:['metadata.id', 'metadata.time', 'data.name', 'data.description', 'partition', 'Level1.Level2.Level3.partition_alt']
+-----+-----------+-------------+
| name|description|partition_alt|
+-----+-----------+-------------+
|name1|      desc1|            3|
|name2|      desc2|            4|
+-----+-----------+-------------+
```

The example demonstrates how to find a deeply nested field. You need to rewrite `get_column` with your own criteria for matching a field name to a complete column name. Here, `get_column` just returns the first field that has a name with `col_name` in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I probably didn't explain it very well. My point is that you wouldn't need to specify the level of columns, like `data.name` and `partition`, but only pass in "columns" and "partition column" (which can be at any nested level, and then generate a create table statement.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect your edit